# How do you login consecutive accounts with Auth0 through Protractor e2e tests?

Tags: angular, authentication, protractor, auth0, incognito-mode

I've got an Angular application (version 2.x.x) that uses Auth0 for logging in (only google accounts are acceptable).

I have Protractor e2e test suites that need to test pieces of the application when a user session is active.  For these actions to be available, a user has to log in, or a token has to be available in localStorage. I want to run multiple suites within a Protractor sequence, for example:

```
describe('Accounts', () => {
  login(user);
  it('should show the dashboard', () => {
    browser.sleep(4000);
    const url = browser.getCurrentUrl();
    expect(url).toEqual('http://localhost:4200/dashboard');
  });
  logout();
  login(user2);
  it('should show the dashboard 2', () => {
    browser.sleep(4000);
    const url = browser.getCurrentUrl();
    expect(url).toEqual('http://localhost:4200/dashboard');
  });
  logout();
});
```

`Login` and `logout` are helper functions. `Login` goes through the Google forms to add the email and address. On success, a json web token is added to localStorage. Logout clears localStorage and takes the user back to the Auth0 Lock.

The second test fails because Auth0 has stored some things in the cache.  `Login` starts with a `browser.get`, but there's no noticeable change in the second spec.  If I were to click on the available "Not your account" button in the second login, Auth0 logs me in with the previously logged in account, which is different if you're not in Chrome Incognito.  In that case, you get a list of accounts you can log into.  What I want is to get the input fields every time I call the login function.

Alternatively, I could set a JWT in localStorage after the `browser.get` is called perhaps, but if I call `browser.executeScript(startSession(user.email))`, where `startSession` is a helper function that generates a JWT and adds it to localStorage with `localStorage.setItem('token', token)`, Protractor says "localStorage is undefined", or "window is undefined" (if I specify window.localStorage).

So all of my tests run individually and pass, but I want to push this up to a continuous integration platform, where all tests can run in sequence.

I've also tried to clear the cache, because even though I've logged the user out, Auth0 still remembers which account I previously logged in as (only in Incognito).

How do I do that?

How do I restart the Incognito session?

How do I inject a dynamic JWT into localStorage?

How do I clear the stuff that Auth0 stores?

Or is there another

Answer (score 0):

My current logout method just clears the localStorage.  This isn't sufficient because it doesn't clear the SSO (Single Sign Out) cookies.  Those cookies arn't available from `window.cookie`.  However, if you redirect the user to `https://your-project.auth0.com/logout?federated`, you'll clear all the cookies and be directed to log into a google account.

Link to Auth0 docs for logging out that clears these sessions.

https://auth0.com/docs/logout#set-the-allowed-logout-urls-at-the-account-level

Interestingly, I didn't get this browser behavior with Chrome normally. I only got it when I checked Firefox and Google Incognito.